# Position mapicon below mapcontrol center

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

please I need help with positioning of the mapicon below the mapcontrol.center point like this screenshot here http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/sygic-gps-navigation-maps-poi-route-directions/340f7b71-86bc-4f99-8c59-d4a6126c10b1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose a different option by using 'RenderTransform' which enable me to extend the 'MapControl' below the bottom of the page and thereby moving the 'MapIcon' and MapControl center closer to the bottom of the page just as i wanted. Its not clean but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NormalizedAnchorPoint` property of the `MapIcon` class. It takes a `Point`, with x and y ranging from 0 to 1.
Based on your screenshot (3rd one), you should use a value of (0.5, 1).

```
MapIcon icon = new MapIcon();
icon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek the  'icon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);'  is the anchor point is the point on the child element that is positioned at the geographic location on the MapControl specified by the MapControl.Location attached property.  It did not work for me. I want to offset the mapcontrol center to somewhere close to the bottom

Comment: Are you trying to tilt the map? Can you give me an illustration (wireframe etc) of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek please follow the link to the screenshot of the sygic navigation app, you'll see that the Mapicon is position close the buttom of the app and not the center