# Setting the MapControl.TransformOrigin

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

please How do I use the MapControl `TransformOrigin property` to center the `Map` and `MapIcon` close to the bottom like this screenshot [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/sygic-gps-navigation-maps-poi-route-directions/340f7b71-86bc-4f99-8c59-d4a6126c10b1) or another way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position mapicon below mapcontrol center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808480/position-mapicon-below-mapcontrol-center)

Comment: @Depechie this question has not been answered either